# Finding the adjoint of an operator defined on $C\left [ 0, 1 \right ]$

Tags: functional-analysis

Find the adjoint of an $\ Ux\left ( t \right )=x\left ( t \right )+t\int_{0}^{t}x\left ( s^2 \right )ds$, defined on $C\left [ 0, 1 \right ]$.
I have $$\left (Ux\left ( t \right ), y\left ( t \right )  \right )=\int_{0}^{1}Ux\left ( t \right )y\left ( t \right )dt=\int_{0}^{1}\left (x\left ( t \right )+t\int_{0}^{t}x\left ( s^2 \right )  ds\right )y\left ( t \right )dt=\\ =\int_{0}^{1}x\left ( t \right )y\left ( t \right )dt+\int_{0}^{1}\left (t\int_{0}^{t^2}\frac{x\left ( u \right )}{2\sqrt{u}}du  \right )y\left ( t \right )dt= \\ =\int_{0}^{1}x\left ( t \right )y\left ( t \right )dt+\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x\left ( u \right )}{2\sqrt{u}}\left (\int_{\sqrt{u}}^{1}ty\left ( t \right )dt  \right )du$$But I have no idea how to continue.
Also I need to find $U^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are done: you have shown that $$\langle Ux,y\rangle=\langle x,Vy\rangle, $$ where $$ Vy(u)= y (u)+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{u}}\left (\int_{\sqrt{u}}^{1}ty\left ( t \right )dt  \right )du. $$

Comment: Thanks. And what about $U^2$?